# Queen corner round trip

Tags: famous-games, queens, rooks

In "The Ink War", Hendriks "complained" that in some game,
during the Zukertort manouvre Q-e8-h8-a1-h1 the bQ didn't start at a8.

Do you know a game with a Q corner round trip in this fashion
(adjacent moves - order of corners is uninteresting), or with a rook?
I'm very sure at least a game with nonadjacent visiting of all corners
by a piece (maybe even a knight or king) exists, and in problem chess this
4# theme has been shown even by myself (not even considering studies).

Comment: Is it necessary for the piece to return to the corner where it started?

Comment: Way cooler...but not actually. (The problems I mentioned show even this, e.g.: Jan Dobrusky, Schachmatnoe Obozrenie, 1901)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CQL query:

```
cql(input Mega_Database_2023.pgn)

flipcolor {
    piece MP in [QR] {
        flip
        line singlecolor nestban --> move from (MP & a1) to h1
                                 --> move from MP to h8
                                 --> move from MP to a8

    }
}
```

when run against Mega Database 2023 returns only 9 (!) games where a queen participated in this movement pattern. Here are some interesting ones:

```
[Event "Maastricht Limburg op-A 9th"]
[Site "Maastricht"]
[Date "2015.05.23"]
[Round "2"]
[White "Liedmann, Dennis"]
[Black "Van den Ouden, Lendert"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "A48"]
[WhiteElo "2157"]
[BlackElo "2105"]
[StartPly "138"]
[FEN ""]

1.d4 d5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.e3 c5 4.b3 cxd4 5.exd4 g6 6.Nbd2 Bg7
7.Bb2 O-O 8.c4 Nc6 9.Bd3 b6 10.Qe2 Bb7 11.Rc1 Nh5 12.Qe3 dxc4 13.bxc4 Rc8 14.
O-O Qd6 15.g3 Rfd8 16.Ne4 Qd7 17.Rfd1 Nxd4 18.Bxd4 Bxd4 19.Qg5 Bg7 20.c5 Bxe4
21.Bxe4 Qxd1+ 22.Rxd1 Rxd1+ 23.Kg2 Nf6 24.cxb6 axb6 25.Bb7 Rc7 26.Ba6 Nd5 27.
Be2 Bf6 28.Qh6 Bg7 29.Qh4 Rdc1 30.Qa4 Rc8 31.Qd7 e6 32.Ng5 R1c7 33.Qd6 Bf8 34.
Qe5 Bg7 35.Qd6 Rc5 36.Ba6 Rf8 37.Bb7 Ne3+ 38.fxe3 Rxg5 39.Qxb6 Bf6 40.Qb4 Rb8
41.a4 Kg7 42.Qb6 Bd8 43.Qd4+ Bf6 44.Qa7 Be5 45.a5 Bxg3 46.hxg3 Rxb7 47.Qxb7
Rxa5 48.Qb2+ Kg8 49.e4 Rg5 50.Qf6 h6 51.Kf3 Rb5 52.Kf4 Rg5 53.g4 Rb5 54.Ke3 h5
55.e5 Rb3+ 56.Kf4 hxg4 57.Kxg4 Rb1 58.Qf2 Rh1 59.Kf4 Rh5 60.Ke4 Rf5 61.Qh4 Kg7
62.Kd4 Kg8 63.Qg3 Kg7 64.Qh2 Kg8 65.Kc5 Kg7 66.Kd6 Rg5 67.Qf4 Rf5 68.Qh4 Rf1
69.Ke7 Rf5 70.Qh1 Rxe5 71.Qa1 f6 72.Qa8 Kh6 73.Qh8+ 1-0
```

---

```
[Event "Mar del Plata op 34th"]
[Site "Mar del Plata"]
[Date "2003.04.19"]
[Round "9"]
[White "Needleman, Alejandro"]
[Black "Moreda, Lucas"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "B16"]
[WhiteElo "2417"]
[BlackElo "2329"]
[StartPly "112"]
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nf6 5.Nxf6+ gxf6 6.Bc4
Rg8 7.Qh5 e6 8.Qxh7 Rxg2 9.Be3 Nd7 10.Qe4 Rg7 11.Ne2 Nb6 12.Bb3 Bd7 13.O-O-O
Qc7 14.Bf4 Bd6 15.Rdg1 Rxg1+ 16.Rxg1 O-O-O 17.Rg7 Nd5 18.Bg3 Qa5 19.c3 f5 20.
Qg2 Qa6 21.Kd2 Nf6 22.Bxd6 Ne4+ 23.Ke1 Nxd6 24.Qg3 c5 25.dxc5 Ne4 26.Qe5 Qd3
27.Qd4 Qf3 28.c6 Bxc6 29.Qxa7 Qh1+ 30.Ng1 Nd6 31.Bxe6+ Kc7 32.Bxf7 Qe4+ 33.Qe3
Qb1+ 34.Ke2 Rd7 35.Qe5 Qxb2+ 36.Kd1 Ba4+ 37.Bb3 Bxb3+ 38.axb3 Qxb3+ 39.Kc1 Qa3+
40.Kc2 Qa2+ 41.Kd1 Qxf2 42.Rxd7+ Kxd7 43.Ne2 Qf1+ 44.Kc2 Qg2 45.Kd3 Qh3+ 46.Qg3
Qf1 47.Qf4 Qb1+ 48.Ke3 Qb6+ 49.Qd4 Qc6 50.h4 Qg2 51.c4 b6 52.Qf4 Qh3+ 53.Kd4
Qb3 54.Ke5 Qd1 55.Nd4 Qe1+ 56.Kd5 Qh1+ 57.Ke5 57...Qa1 58.Kf6 Qa8 59.Nxf5 59...Qh8+ 60.Kg6 Qe8+ 61.Kh6 Qf8+ 62.Kg5 Qg8+ 63.Kh5 Qf7+ 64.Kg4
Qg6+ 65.Qg5 Qe6 66.Qf4 Nxc4 67.Qd4+ Kc6 68.Kf4 b5 69.Qe4+ Qxe4+ 70.Kxe4 b4 71.
h5 Nd2+ 72.Kd3 Nf3 73.Nd4+ Kd6 74.Nxf3 Ke6 75.Ng1 1-0
```

---

```
[Event "RUS-chT 27th"]
[Site "Sochi"]
[Date "2020.11.26"]
[Round "7.5"]
[White "Alexeev, Alexey"]
[Black "Tsoi, Dmitry"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[ECO "A85"]
[WhiteElo "2246"]
[BlackElo "2315"]
[StartPly "122"]
[FEN ""]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 c6 4.Nf3 f5 5.Bg5 Nf6 6.e3 Bd6 7.
Be2 O-O 8.Bh4 Qe8 9.Bg3 Qe7 10.Bxd6 Qxd6 11.Ne5 Nbd7 12.f4 Qe7 13.O-O Nxe5 14.
fxe5 Ne8 15.Qd2 g5 16.Rab1 Bd7 17.b4 a6 18.a4 Nc7 19.c5 Ne8 20.b5 axb5 21.axb5
Ng7 22.bxc6 bxc6 23.Rb7 Ra3 24.Qb2 Rfa8 25.Rb8+ Rxb8 26.Qxb8+ Be8 27.Qb4 Qa7
28.Rb1 h6 29.Kf2 Kh7 30.Rb3 Rxb3 31.Qxb3 Qa1 32.Bd3 h5 33.Nb1 Qa7 34.Qa3 Qb7
35.g3 h4 36.Nd2 Bh5 37.gxh4 g4 38.Nf1 Qe7 39.Ng3 Qxh4 40.Kg1 Be8 41.Qb2 Qd8 42.
Qf2 Qa5 43.Ne2 Qd2 44.Nf4 Qc1+ 45.Kg2 Kg8 46.Kg3 Bf7 47.Ba6 Qb1 48.Bf1 Kf8 49.
h3 gxh3 50.Kxh3 Ne8 51.Kg3 Nc7 52.Bd3 Qc1 53.Kf3 Bh5+ 54.Nxh5 Qh1+ 55.Ke2 Qxh5+
56.Kd2 Ke7 57.Qg1 Qh7 58.Qg5+ Kd7 59.Be2 Kc8 60.Bh5 Kb7 61.Qg6 Qh8 62.Qf7 Qa8 63.Ke1 Qa1+ 64.Kf2 Qh1 65.Be2 Qh4+ 66.Kf3 Qe1 67.Qd7
Qa1 68.Bd3 Qh1+ 69.Kf2 Qh2+ 70.Kf3 Qa2 71.Be2 Qa3 72.Bf1 Qa1 73.Be2 Qh1+ 74.Kf2
Qh4+ 75.Kf3 Qh1+ 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: Accepted this one, because CQL :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Tim Krabbe #354.](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary18txt.htm)

Starting on move 59.

```
[Title "Joukl-Lamac, Czech Republic"]
[FEN "1b6/1k6/3p4/2pKp3/2P5/8/8/R7 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rh1 Kb6 2. Rh8 Bc7 3. Ra8 Kb7 4. Ra1 Bb8 5. Rf1 Kb6 6. Rf8 Bc7 7. Ke6 Kc6 8. Rc8 1-0
```

And another, on move  75.

```
[Title "Ernst-Van der Marel Groningen 1999"]
[startflipped ""]
[FEN "8/8/4k3/6P1/6K1/8/5R2/7r b - - 0 1"]

1... Ra1 2. Kh5 Ra8 3. g6 Rh8+ 4. Kg5 Rh1 5. Re2+ 1-0
```

Comment: Since I'm a Krabbe peruser, I should have remembered (to add insult to injury, I was even featured in #353 :-) In case someone digs up an adjacent Q example soon (Krabbe gives nonadjacent), the award goes to that person, otherwise I'll accept this one.

Comment: Did Ernst really throw away the win after the ridiculous Re2+ instead of the obvious Kg5 and Lucena? Is the psychological effect of the roundabout trip of the black rook that strong?

Comment: @Evargalo No, it was a win. Forgot to include the 1-0.

Comment: @RewanDemontay So 5.Re2+?? was never played I suppose, it is just an artefact of registering the moves (probably human-wise and not with an electronic board back in 1999). I think that move can safely be edited out.

Comment: @Evargalo What is the confusion here? White played Re2+, then Black resigned on their turn. As Krabbe put it: "This homerun was a swan song: 75...Ra1 76.Kh5 Ra8 77.g6 Rh8+ 78.Kg5 Rh1 79.Re2+ and Black resigned."

Comment: Oh, I found only now the source of the confusion : In your answer you put 4.Kg4 (after which 4...Rh1 5.Re2?? Kf6 is a draw), while Krabbé's blog the correct move is given: 4.Kg5! Rh1 5.Re2 and Black's resignation is indeed forced.